# FileMaker Hide and show field based on another field

Tags: boolean, field, hide, conditional-statements, filemaker

Can you help me with this?

I want to make a layout like this:

Meal? Yes No (with radio button set). If the user chooses Yes, then Dessert field will show up with drop-down menu to select.

Since I'm new to FileMaker 14, I can't figure out how to set Meal with Boolean values, so that when Meal is Yes (true), then Dessert will show up; or when Meal is No (false), Dessert is hidden.

From the guide, it shows how to work with numbers or IsEmpty(field), that means the field is not selected at all. In my case, it's more like a condition and it works with words, not numbers.

Thank you for reading this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to set Meal with Boolean values

A simple way is to use a value list with a single value of `1`. Then make the Meal field a Number field, format it as a checkbox, and make it sufficiently narrow so that users don't see the `1`. With this in place, you can formulate your hiding condition as `not Meal`.

With your current arrangement, where Meal is a Text field formatted as a Yes/No radio button set, you can use `Meal ≠ "Yes"` as your hiding formula. This will hide the Dessert field when the Meal field is empty or contains `"No"`.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Actually, I tried Meal = "Yes" and it works.